# There exists an open set $A:=(a_1,b_1)\cup (a_2,b_2)\cup\dots$ such that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ does not have measure zero Munkres Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Example 1 on p.113:
> We construct a bounded open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ does not have measure zero.
>
> The rational numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$ are countable; let us arrange them in a sequence $q_1,q_2,\dots$. Let $0<a<1$ be fixed. For each $i$, choose an open interval $(a_i,b_i)$ of length less than $\frac{a}{2^i}$ that contains $q_i$ and is contained in $(0,1)$. These intervals will overlap, of course, but that doesn't matter. Let $A$ be the following open set of $\mathbb{R}$: $$A=(a_1,b_1)\cup (a_2,b_2)\cup\dots.$$

The author proved that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ doesn't have measure zero.

My question is here:
$S:=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}\cup\{b_1,b_2,\dots\}$ is a countable set.
So, $S$ has measure zero.
So, there exists $b\in\operatorname{Bd}A$ such that $b\notin S$.
What is $b$?
Please give me an example of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$q_i\in (a_i, b_i) $ implies $A$ contains all rationals implies $A$ is dense.

Hence $\overline{A}=[0, 1]$

$\begin{align}m(\overset{o}{A})\le m(A) \le\sum_{i} &\ell (a_i, b_i) \\&\le \sum_i \frac{a}{2^i}\\&=a\end{align}$

$\operatorname{Bd}A =\overline{A}\setminus \overset{o}{A}$

$\begin{align}m(\operatorname{Bd}A )&=m[0, 1]-m(\overset{o}{A})\\&\ge1-a\end{align}$

Comment: Lost in Space, Thank you very much for your answer.